# OpenVPN client doesn´t connect to OpenVPN server

Tags: windows, vpn, openvpn, vpn-client, client-server

I followed the guides provided by two youtube videos, [Install and Configure OpenVPN Server in Windows PC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GwhBdOGlglc) and [how to Install & Setup OpenVPN on windows 10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dp0Na3o-8Zw), step by step. However, client doesn´t establishes a conexion to server. I always get the error that client waited to long to create the conexion or that and handshake failed as well.

I tried the first video, didn´t work, uninstall and delete everything, the second one, the same problem.

I installed the OpenVPN server in a virtual machine with Windows 10 Pro 22H2 x64 and the OpenVPNclient located on my PC, with the same OS.

On both devices I used the Windows 64-bit MSI installer program from the official website [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/community-downloads/)

Comment: What are the exact error messages in your vpn client log? `C:\Program Files\OpenVPN Connect\agent.log`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is what the OpenVPN Connect Log says [Mega](https://mega.nz/file/giFinQQa#H4m7EVYzjyV8PNpUOJCiLXZwvMhcBFZaXvKM85XEgVs)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like on your public ip the udp port 1194 can't be reached.
Please verify that your openvpn server vm is reachable on that ip and port.

And I'm have my doubts if that will ever work, because OpenVPN needs to be directly reachable from the internet.

I did a quick nmap scan on your public ip which is listed in the agent logs and UDP port 1194 seems to be closed / not reachable